# Seeing the UIButton in another void - iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton

I have set a UIButton like this :

```
UIButton *learnmorebutton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
```

and I have

```
[learnmorebutton addTarget:self action:@selector(myAction) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

and i have a void

```
- (void)myAction
{

}
```

but i cannot see `learnmorebutton` in the `void`, and thats because `@property`.
is this correct ?

Comment: I want to set a new background colour when its pressed.

Comment: Please find a good Objective-C tutorial and learn about variable scope.

Comment: ... what? Is **what** correct? You want to change the background color **of what?** You need to provide more specifics, and also (as @rmaddy mentioned) learn about variable scope (and not just in Objective-C but in programming in general.

Comment: background colour of button

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All UIControls pass themselves as a "sender" to their target action methods ***IF*** the selector you give them takes 1 parameter.

Make these changes:(note the colon after the myAction selector on the first line)

```
[learnmorebutton addTarget:self action:@selector(myAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

- (void)myAction:(UIButton *)sender
{
    //sender is the button that was tapped
    sender.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor]; //or whatever color you wanted here.
}
```